# mobx-state-tree Error while converting `""` to `AnonymousModel[]`

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I am getting this error but I don't know why. I am running mobx state tree (3.2.4)

```
:8080/main.js:52013 Uncaught (in promise) Error: [mobx-state-tree] Error while converting `""` to `AnonymousModel[]`:

    value `""` is not assignable to type: `AnonymousModel[]` (Value is not an array).
    at fail (:8080/main.js:52013)
    at typecheck$$1 (:8080/main.js:51692)
    at typecheckInternal$$1 (:8080/main.js:51678)
    at ArrayType$$1../node_modules/mobx-state-tree/dist/mobx-state-tree.module.js.ArrayType$$1.applySnapshot (:8080/main.js:52884)
    at executeAction (:8080/main.js:55058)
    at ArrayType$$1.res (:8080/main.js:55050)
    at :8080/main.js:50844
    at executeAction (:8080/main.js:55058)
    at res (:8080/main.js:55050)
    at runMiddleWares (:8080/main.js:51533)
```

I cannot see any indication I am trying to set an empty string to an array.

How can I pinpoint what property it is trying to apply?

Comment: Definitely would help to see some code :) At first glance it seems similar to the error described here: https://mobx-state-tree.gitbook.io/docs/getting-started#meeting-types so you may have something of that sort happening.

Answer (score 1):

Not easy to reply without code, but probably you're loading [data that is not following the type specification of your model](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree/blob/master/docs/intro/getting-started.md#meeting-types).
It seems you have an empty string instead of an array.

---

Another common mistake is to use an **integer** for a field of type `types.identifier` which expects a string.

Use a `types.identifierNumber` to have numerical ids.